# android passing arguments are correct in first activity , wrong in the second

Tags: android

I am passing arguments from first activity to the second , in the first activity i can see all the arguments , but in the second activity one of the argument is being always `0` , the rest I can see them. I passing `id` , `url`, `likes` the likes argument is always null can you help indentify the issue ?

I am passing data like this , in systemoutprint I am getting value `2`

```
   Listitem listitem = new Listitem(item.getOrder(), item.getId(), item.getUrl(), item.getUserName(), item.getLikes());

                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,SingleObjectActivity.class);

                System.out.println(item.getUrl()); //i can see correct value
                System.out.println(item.getLikes());//i can see correct value

                        intent.putExtra("Object_list", (Parcelable) listitem);


                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

here is second activity the url is correct  , the `likes` getting always `0`

```
 Listitem li = ((Listitem) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Object_list"));
    calc= li.getLikes();
    id=li.getId();
    System.out.println(li.getLikes());
```

here is the logcat

```
09-14 20:21:00.069 8874-8874/com.justedhak.www.i I/System.out: http://justedhak.com/old-files/images/uploaded_images57d985894b416.png
09-14 20:21:00.069 8874-8874/com.justedhak.www.i I/System.out: 2
09-14 20:21:00.069 8874-8874/com.justedhak.www.i I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.justedhak.www.i time:16396709
09-14 20:21:00.199 8874-8874/com.justedhak.www.i I/System.out: 0
```

here is the listitem , I though might problem with the `writeToParcel`

```
public Listitem(int order, String id, String url, String userName, int likes) {
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.order = order;
    this.likes = likes;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}


public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(int likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.id);
    // dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.url);
    dest.writeInt(this.likes);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Listitem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Listitem>() {
    public Listitem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Listitem(in);
    }

    public Listitem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Listitem[size];
    }
};

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public int getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(int order) {
    this.order = order;
}
```

}

Comment: your intent code seems to be correct. You didn't show your read from parcel code, so it might be there too. Regardless, parcelable code is a pain in the ass to do, so I suggest you to use a library that makes it automatically. This one https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler all you have to do is put the `@Parcel` annotation and use the `Parcels.wrap` and `Parcels.unwrap` static methods

Comment: @Budius you are right the problem is i didnt put readpracel , I am checking example for that , add it as answer at least to upvote it and if it worked ill accept btw ill check the parceler later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent code seems to be correct.

You didn't show your read from parcel code, so it might be there too.

Regardless, parcelable code is a pain in the ass to do, so I suggest you to use a library that makes it automatically. This one github.com/johncarl81/parceler all you have to do is put the `@Parcel` annotation and use the `Parcels.wrap` and `Parcels.unwrap` static methods

example:

```
intent.putExtra("Object_list", Parcels.wrap(listitem));

// then

Listitem li = (Listitem) Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Object_list"));
```

Comment: I was checking the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html , they didnt say how to add read parcel ,  how to add it read parcel in my code to work correct ?